# ISnull function required two arguments

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am converting my MSAccess query to SQL view but not able to replicate the error

```
Create View [Employees Extended]
AS
SELECT IIf(IsNull([Last Name]),IIf(IsNull([First Name]),[Company],[First Name])
,IIf(IsNull([First Name]),[Last Name],[Last Name] & "," & [First Name])) AS [File As]
,IIf(IsNull([Last Name]),IIf(IsNull([First Name]),[Company],[First Name])
,IIf(IsNull([First Name]),[Last Name],[First Name] & " " & [Last Name])) AS [Employee Name], Employees.*
FROM Employees
ORDER BY IIf(IsNull([Last Name]),IIf(IsNull([First Name]),[Company],[First Name])
,IIf(IsNull([First Name]),[Last Name],[Last Name] & ", " & [First Name]))
,IIf(IsNull([Last Name]),IIf(IsNull([First Name]),[Company],[First Name])
,IIf(IsNull([First Name]),[Last Name],[First Name] & " " & [Last Name]));
```

> `ISNull` required two arguments

Comment: Please explain the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: `ISNULL` means something different in T-SQL. Use `x IS NULL` instead. Expressions of the form `IIf(IsNull(x), y, x)` (of which you have several instances) can be rewritten more succinctly as `ISNULL(x, y)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `ISNULL(ColumnName)` with `ColumnName IS NULL`.

`ISNULL` is SQL Server dosen't not return a Boolean result dependant on whether the expression inside returns `NULL`. `ISNULL` will return the value of the second parameter, if the first has the value of `NULL` (the data type returned will be the datatype of the first parameter).

So for example, in the following query:

```
SELECT ISNULL(A,B)
FROM (VALUES('a',1),
            (NULL,2),
            ('b',NULL)) V(A,B);
```

The following values would be returned:

```
'a'
'2'  --note this is a string, not an integer
'b'
```

Answer (score 3):

I would express this logic:

```
IIf(IsNull([Last Name]),
    IIf(IsNull([First Name]),
       [Company],[First Name]
       ),
    IIf(IsNull([First Name]),
        [Last Name],
        [Last Name] & "," & [First Name]
       )
    ) AS [File As]
```

In SQL Server as:

```
COALESCE([First Name] + ',', '') + [Last Name]
```

Actually, I would use similar logic in MS Access:

```
NZ([First Name] & ",", "") & [Last Name]
```

In SQL Server, you should be using:

- `+` or `CONCAT()` to concatenate strings
- Single quotes not double quotes for string functions
- `IS NULL` to compare to `NULL` values
- `COALESCE()` to replace a `NULL` value with something else
- Other string functions as appropriate for your problem